# if и ternary в return

Tags: javascript

Почему в return нельзя вставить if

```js
function(foo){
 return( if(...){...}else{...} )
}
```

Тернарный оператор работает как нужно.

```js
function(foo){
 return( x ? y : z )
}
```

Comment: а чем вам тернарный оператор не подходит?

Comment: Тернарный подходит. Хочется понять почему if не подходит.

Comment: Во первых сам по себе if ничего не возвращает, это оператор а не функция, что вернуть - не ясно

Comment: А если в if тоже прописать return.

Comment: А почему не запихнуть ретурн в иф, а не наоборот?

Comment: А если в if прописать return то он всё равно будет ретурном функции, а не ретурном ифа

Comment: Спасибо. Тернарный оператор _возвращает_ выражения, а if _выполняет_ инструкции.   вроде так

Comment: Для тернарного не нужны скобки, кстати)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратимся к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-return-statement):

```
ReturnStatement[Yield, Await]:
    return ;
    return [no LineTerminator here] Expression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await];
```

Здесь видно, что после `return` должно идти *выражение*, в то время как [`if` является statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#prod-IfStatement)

Поэтому нельзя делать `return if...`

В то же время [тернарный оператор](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-conditional-operator) является *выражением* именно поэтому его допустимо использовать вместе с `return`.